# Average of different subsets of variables with condition in R

Tags: r, subset, average

Sample data:

```
    
ID  month1  month2   month3   month4   month5  month6  month7  month8  month9  month10   b1  b2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   12      14        15         45      12      12       11    12       78     28      3   9
2   14      15        45         14      15      45       14    19       22     27      4   8
3   14      13        25         74      25      45       14    19       22     27      5   10
.
.
.
.
70.....    ....                           .....                                    ......1   8
```

I want to calculate the average of the "month"-variables (for each ID) based on the difference between b**1** (interview**1** month) and b**2** (interview**2** month). So the averages will be row wise

for example, for ID=1, who was first interviewed in **month 3** and then again in **month 9**, the average will be (month3 +  month4 + month5 + month6 + month7 + month8  month9)/7, which is (15 + 45 + 12 + 12 + 11 + 12 + 78)/7=26.42

and

for ID= 2, average will be (month4 + month5 +month6+ month7 +month8)/5

and so on..

I am working on R-studio. So, I will prefer a code written in that. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: sample data: ```df <- data.frame(ID = c("1","2","3"),
                 month1 = c("12","14","14"),
                 month2 = c("14","15","13"),
                 month3 = c("15","45","25"),
                 month4 = c("45","14","74"),
                 month5 = c("12","15","25"),
                 month6 = c("12","45","45"),
                 month7 = c("11","14","14"),
                 month8 = c("12","19","19"),
                 month9 = c("78","22","22"),
                 month10 = c("28","27","27"),
                 b1 = c("3","4","5"),
                 b2 = c("9","8","10"))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works provided that the order of your variables is not changing.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(avg = mean(c_across((b1+1):(b2+1)), na.rm =TRUE)) %>%
  select(-ID)

# Rowwise: 
  month1 month2 month3 month4 month5 month6 month7 month8 month9 month10    b1    b2   avg
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     12     14     15     45     12     12     11     12     78      28     3     9  26.4
2     14     15     45     14     15     45     14     19     22      27     4     8  24.9
3     14     13     25     74     25     45     14     19     22      27     5    10  32
```

Sample data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~ID,  ~month1,  ~month2,   ~month3,   ~month4,   ~month5,  ~month6,  ~month7,  ~month8,  ~month9,  ~month10,   ~b1,  ~b2,
    1,   12,      14,        15,         45,      12,      12,       11,    12,       78,     28,      3,   9,
  2,   14,      15,        45,         14,      15,      45,       14,    19,       22,     27,      4,   8,
  3,   14,      13,        25,         74,      25,      45,       14,    19,       22,     27,      5,   10,
)
```

Comment: You can omit `select(-ID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Base R option using `mapply` :

```
cols <- grep('month', names(df), value = TRUE)
df$result <- mapply(function(x, y, z) mean(unlist(df[x,cols[y:z]]),na.rm = TRUE),
                     seq(nrow(df)), df$b1, df$b2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to go by row, subset the vector and calculate the mean:

```
apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) mean(as.numeric(x[x[11]:x[12]])))
#[1] 26.42857 21.40000 25.33333
```